# Address of public SFTP test server

Tags: integration-testing, sftp

In my application I want to download file from SFTP server and for that I written one program but now I want to test it whether its working fine or not. So I need one public SFTP server so that I will download any file from it. I know public FTP server but don't know about any SFTP server. So can anyone know such SFTP server?

Answer (score 12):

I'm using the Free Mini SFTP server linked from this page: http://www.coreftp.com/server/

It runs local which is fine for my testing.  If you need a remote host, it won't help.

Answer (score 11):

have a look at this Tiny SFTP Server http://www.andrewfriedl.com/2012/06/an-sftp-test-server-you-can-run-on-your-desktop/

**Update:**

this seems to be a new Free SFTP Server to test: http://labs.rebex.net/tiny-sftp-server

Comment: Link is dead, the blog is abandoned. You can try http://labs.rebex.net/tiny-sftp-server instead. It uses newer version of the same core and is also free.

Comment: tiny-sftp-server work fine.. easy and no config require

Answer (score 9):

I found this publically accessible *SFTP* server at Washington University in St. Louis today:

`sftp://itcsubmit.wustl.edu`

You can visit http://itcsubmit.wustl.edu/icons/ServerAccessTest.html for some information about it:

> This page is provided by the ITC for testing network connectivity to the ITC Secure FTP (SFTP) server.

...

> If you can access this page with a web browser, but cannot connect to the server using an SFTP client, it is quite likely that your institution's firewall or proxy configuration is preventing an outgoing connection to TCP port 22

Comment: I tried accessing sftp://itcsubmit.wustl.edu , it is asking me for username and password, and am not sure what it will be?